# Cannot do inverse search with vim's latex-suite and YAP

Tags: vim, vim-latex, dvi-mode, yap

Though forward search works fine, something is going wrong with the inverse search. In YAP, the command line for inverse DVI search is set to be

```
C:\Users\user\Vim\vim80\gvim.exe -c ":RemoteOpen +%l %f"
```

If I execute `:echo g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi`, I get the output

```
latex -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode $*
```

If I double click at a location in the generated dvi document, my current Gvim windows closes and another empty gvim window opens which has the following things written at the bottom:

```
/Users/username/Desktop/Vimtex [noperm]
:let g:Remote_Server = 1
```

Could someone help me in setting up inverse search?

EDIT: I have understood that the error is occuring when the filename `%f` has a whitespace. Could someone tell me how to allow whitespace containing filenames too?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `-src-special` method is obsolete. Are you sure you want to use DVI files?

Comment: I am fine with using any of dvi or pdf. I just want to get forward and reverse search working. Could you point me in the right direction?